# Is there a way in python to tell if a variable is a system command

Tags: python, command-line

I'm making a shell emulator in python, however I want to have to user input saved to a variable named x, and if it is a system command

I have tried to have a list of every command their was, however that was too time consuming

```
import os
while True:
  execute = input(">")
  os.system(execute)
```

Comment: What means "system command"? A command processed by the shell? A program that is part of the OS?

Comment: Micheal Butscher, A command processed by the shell, like echo or clear/cls

Comment: This is not possible. Each shell has its own set of shell commands. I don't know a general method to list them.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this.  The best you can do is is call `which` on the entered command, and then examine the return value.

Comment: Or just go ahead and try to execute it, and let it fail if it's not a command.

Comment: but how can I tell if it fails? All I get is sh: "command": not found as an output

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list of commands you could do something like this:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def get_stderr(cmd):
...     return Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=PIPE).communicate()[1]
... 
>>> 
>>> for c in ['garbage_cmd1', 'grep', 'which', 'garbage_cmd2']:
...     if 'not found' in get_stderr(c).decode():
...         print('%s is not valid' % c)
...     else:
...         print('%s is valid' % c)
... 
garbage_cmd1 is not valid
grep is valid
which is valid
garbage_cmd2 is not valid
```

If you are on a Linux machine you could also run `compgen -c >> cmds.txt`

Comment: Isn't `compgen` bash-specific?

Comment: Yes but there was mo mention of your OS?

Comment: for each OS there are multiple possible shells.

Comment: If you need to analyze multiple shells, it might be better to look at the PATH variable/save all possible directories, and then look at each path directory’s contents and check if each item is an exe using a function similar to the one above